# How to replace text in files with a text that has complicated characaters?

Tags: text, sed, replace, gnupg

I need to run the operation below but the bash or zsh terminal does not like those characters. How do I run it properly?

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/PHRASE=TEST/pwds=`gpg --decrypt ~/test.gpg` & eval "$pwds"/gI' {} \;
```

`PHRASE=TEST`  needs to be replaced by `pwds=`gpg --decrypt ~/test.gpg`& eval "$pwds"`

I do not need to use sed, I cna use another thing as long as it works

Comment: One thing is that part of your substitution text (`~/text.gpg`) contains the `/` delimiter of the `s` command. You can either escape that (`~\/text.gpg`) or use a different delimiter (e.g. `s|...|...|gI`). To get more help, though, please post a line of sample input with your expected output.

Comment: This is the exact thing I am trying to do, so I need the exact line that works. What is in my example what is replaced by what. What example line do I need to provide, not sure

Comment: see my post, I added what I need. Thanks for the example lines but they do not work.

Comment: Do not work in what way? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error? If the problem is that the output is not what you expect, then show the input, the output you are getting, and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample input and expected output, I can't verify 100%, but I'm pretty sure you just need to escape the `/` in the file path and the `&`:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/PHRASE=TEST/pwds=`gpg --decrypt ~\/test.gpg` \& eval "$pwds"/gI' {} \;
```

Or if you prefer you can avoid the first escape by changing the delimiter of the `s` command:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's|PHRASE=TEST|pwds=`gpg --decrypt ~/test.gpg` \& eval "$pwds"|gI' {} \;
```

Example:

```
$ cat file.txt
line 1
line 2 PHRASE=TEST
line 3

$ find ./ -type f -exec gsed -i 's/PHRASE=TEST/pwds=`gpg --decrypt ~\/test.gpg` \& eval "$pwds"/gI' {} \;

$ cat file.txt
line 1
line 2 pwds=`gpg --decrypt ~/test.gpg` & eval "$pwds"
line 3
```

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 110: unterminated `s' command although I used the second line of yours, I will try the first one